# Probability of Getting a Red Ball after Selecting from Three Bins

Tags: probability

I'm trying to calculate probabilities based on a random choice algorithm, and I'm a bit confused about some of the math. Here's the scenario:

Let's say I have three bins (could be any number, but let's say three), and each bin is filled with red, green, and blue balls.

The distribution of balls in the bins are:

- Bin 1

  - Red: 5 (50%)
  - Green: 5 (50%)
  - Blue: 0 (0%)
- Bin 2

  - Red: 8 (80%)
  - Blue: 2 (20%)
- Bin 3

  - Red: 4 (40%)
  - Blue 6 (60%)

If you were to choose one ball from each bin in succession, I'm trying to figure out how likely it would be for you to have gotten a particular ball. In the above example, you would have chosen one ball per bin, for a total of three balls. So, with those three balls, what is the chance that you have a red ball, or the chance you have a green ball, or the chance you have a blue ball?

Based on a discussion [here](http://ask.metafilter.com/36264/How-to-calculate-average-probability), it seems the best way to do this is multiply all the probabilities that I *won't* get what I want, and then just subtract that probability from 100%.

Based on that, I calculated these probabilities:

```
Probability of red ball: (1.0 - (0.5 * 0.2 * 0.6)) = 0.94 = 94%

Probability of green ball: (1.0 - (0.5 * 1 * 1)) = 0.5 = 50%

Probability of blue ball: (1.0 - (1 * 0.8 * 0.4)) = 0.68 = 68%
```

Are these results correct? I was a bit surprised by the outcomes. Are the total probabilities supposed to add to 100% in this scenario?

Comment: Probability of drawing a red ball is $\frac{1}{3}\times 0.5 + \frac{1}{3}\times 0.8 +\frac{1}{3}\times 0.4 = \frac{1.7}{3}$ and probability of getting a green ball is $\frac{0.5}{3}$ and the probability of getting a blue ball is $\frac{0.8}{3}$ and these probabilities indeed add to 1.

Comment: What you describe appears to be the "average probability." Is there some special term for what was described in the question? Which equation conveys "the probability of getting a red ball after choosing from all the bins"?

Comment: To choose a red ball, we first need to choose a bin and then a ball from it. Since it is equally likely to choose any bin, each choice has probability 1/3. Once we have chosen the bin, the probability of choosing a red ball is dependent on the contents of the bin. This is called the law of total probability.

Comment: Oh, to be clear (and I updated the question to hopefully be unambiguous), the idea is that you must pick from each bin in succession. So, you pick one ball from bin 1, a ball from bin 2, a ball from bin 3. Then, after picking a ball from each, what is the probability that one of the selected balls is a red ball?

Comment: The probability $1 - (0.5)(0.2)(0.6)$ is for at least one is a red ball. Similarly the other two probabilities are for at least one is a green ball and for at least one is a blue ball. These three events are not mutually exclusive and exhaustive and hence their probabilities do not add to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to pick a ball from each bin, the probability to get e.g. one red ball is the following:

$P(\text{one red ball})=P(\text{one red ball in bin 1}, \text{no red balls in bin 1 or 2}) + P(\text{one red ball in bin 2}, \text{no red balls in bin 1 or 3}) + P(\text{one red ball in bin 3, no red balls in bin 1 or 3})$

As a pick in each bin does not influence the remaining two bins, you can e.g. calculate (due to independence):

$P(\text{one red ball in bin 1}, \text{no red balls in bin 1 or 2})
=
P(\text{one red ball in bin 1})\cdot P(\text{no red balls in bin 1})\cdot P(\text{no red balls in bin 2})
=
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{3}{5}
=
\frac{3}{50}
=
0{,}06.
$

All in all you would get:

$P(\text{one red ball})
=
0{,}06 + 0{,}24 + 0{,}04
=
0{,}34. 
$

Similarly (and easier),

$P(\text{one blue ball})
=
0{,}56.
$

Similarly (and much easier),

$P(\text{one green ball})
=
0{,}5.
$

Note that the probability of the events do not add up to $1$ as the events do not form a disjoint partition of the possible outcomes.

You are instead computing the probability of at least one e.g. red ball. For the green ball, where you can at most have one, we arrive at the same probability. But for say the red ball, there is a high probability to obtain two or even three balls, which you do not take into account.

Mathematically, you are stating that

$P(\text{one red ball}) = 1 - P(\text{no red ball})
= 1 - P(\text{no red ball in bin 1}) \cdot P(\text{no red ball in bin 2}) \cdot P(\text{no red ball in bin 3}).
$

But the first equality is not true. We have $P(A) = 1 - P(A^c)$ where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$. The complement of $\text{one red ball}$ is not $\text{no red ball}$ but $\text{no red ball or two or three red balls}$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Just to make sure I'm totally understanding, you're saying that the chances of getting EXACTLY one of each type of ball would be (34%, 56%, 50%), and the chances of getting AT LEAST one of each type of ball would be the values I posted (94%, 68%, 50%)?

It's an interesting distinction, and the values make sense to me, in that case. Since there are red balls in each bin, the chance of getting exactly one red ball is much less than getting at least one read ball.

Comment: Exactly. We see how $94>>34$, while $68>56$ and $50=50$ - in fine correspondence with the number of bins with said colour.